# how to add facebook feed to our website

Tags: facebook, web

I am trying to add a facebook feed to a website and for some reason it does not show any activity.

This is the page: gmphomes.com.au/about-us.html

And this is the facebook page that has the activity: facebook.com/pages/GMP-Homes/257003974317783

I have gone into the facebook account, copied over the script from the Social Media section and pasted it into the page.

But when I look at the page gmphomes.com.au/about-us.html it says no activity to display.

Can anyone suggest where we have gone wrong.

I would have though that this would have been an easy thing to do.

Cheers
Malcolm

Answer (score 1):

The activity feed is to display activity to Facebook on your website, such as when people like or share one of your pages. If you want to display activity from your Facebook fan page wall you need a different plugin, maybe the like box http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Answer (score 1):

If you can't display posts from your Facebook page then it's most likely because you have restrictions (either age or location) on the page. You can remove any restrictions by going to your page settings in Facebook and making sure that the page isn't restricted to a certain country or age range. Once you've removed the restrictions then check out the [Custom Facebook Feed plugin](http://smashballoon.com/custom-facebook-feed/).

Answer (score 0):

You have no activity on your wall for it to report.
Please read what an activity feed does here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/

Perhaps you are looking for something instead to display your wall posts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use neosmart STREAM. It's a Social Media Plugin to add Facebook and Twitter walls to a website. neosmart STREAM lite is free and can be downloaded here: https://neosmart-stream.de